# Access (read-only) table on different schema and hbm2ddl generated create-script

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, hibernate-mapping, hbm2ddl

My application uses two schema and two persistence units.

I need that one Business Object mapped on the first schema/PU can read (and only read) data from a table mapped in the second schema/PU.

So I created a class mapped to the "foreign" table, with only the fields that I need with insertable and updatable set to false (so it should be read-only)

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "NETHZ_USER", schema = "IDMANLIGHT" )
@Inheritance( strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED )
public class CMNUser extends PersistentObject
{
    private static final long   serialVersionUID    = CmnSerialVersionUID.getSerialVersionUID();

    @Column( insertable = false, updatable = false )
    private String              firstName;

    @Column( insertable = false, updatable = false )
    private String              lastName;

    @Column( insertable = false, updatable = false )
    private String              nethzPrimaryUsername;

    // Empty constructor need by Hibernate/Envers
    public CMNUser()
    {
        super();
    }

    + getters and setters
```

and put it in the persistence.xml under the first PU too.

The problem is that to create the DB I use the Hibernate Tools (hbm2ddl) and when it generates the script to create the tables for the first PU, it generates the `create table idmanlight.nethz_user` too. When then it tries to execute the script there is the error: "No rights for schema idmanlight" (which is legal).

The point is that hbm2ddl shouldn't generate the creation of the table (which already happens by the second PU).

Is there a way to avoid this?

I hope I explained the problem well enough to be understood...